# Continuity of the Lebesgue measure w.r.t the Hausdorff metric

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, hausdorff-measure

I have a question linked to [Interplay of Hausdorff metric and Lebesgue measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339102/interplay-of-hausdorff-metric-and-lebesgue-measure). Let us denote as $\mathcal K(\mathbb R^n)$ the space of compact subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ endowed with the Hausdorff metric $\rho$ and let $\lambda$ be the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$. I want to know if there are (sufficient) conditions under which the measure $\lambda$ is continuous w.r.t. $\rho$, that is
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\rho(K, K_k)=0\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\lambda(K_k)=\lambda(K).\qquad(\star)
$$
I tried to search it in the books *Fractal geometry* by Kenneth Falconer and *Functions of Bounded Variation and Free Discontinuity Problems* by Ambrosio, Fusco and Pallara but I did not find anything. In the second book it is written that, in the case $n=2$, the Hausdorff measure (which is a rescaling of the usual $\lambda$ on $\mathbb R^n$) is lower-semicontinuous w.r.t. the Hausdorff metric along sequences satisfying a suitable uniform concentration property, but this is not what I am looking for.

Some help? Do you have some references?

Comment: what do you want to put conditions on? the sequence, right?

Comment: @erz I don't know, maybe yes. But on the set $K$ too. I was asking if there are special cases in which the condition $(\star)$ holds.

Comment: $K$ has to be zero measure since finite sets are dense. Is there a zero measure compact that is a limit of $>\epsilon$ measure compacts?

Comment: If $K_k$ converges to $K$, then for any $\varepsilon>0$, $K_k$ is eventually included in $K+B(0,\varepsilon)$. Since $\lambda(K+B(0,\varepsilon))\to0$ as $\varepsilon\to0$ (Lebesgue dominated convergence), the Lebesgue measure is semicontinuous (I want to say upper?).

Comment: Proof by Socratic method

Comment: Conjecture (that I think is not difficult to prove with the above comments): for all neighbourhood $U$ for some fixed $K$, the set $\lambda_*(U)=\lbrace \lambda(K'),\ K'\in U\rbrace$ contains $[0,\lambda(K)]$; more precisely, the intersection of all $\lambda_*(U)$ where $U$ ranges over all neighbourhoods of $K$ is precisely $[0,\lambda(K)]$. I think I can write that down if it is of interest.

Comment: @PierrePC and is it actually an interval?

Comment: @VilleSalo Yes, precisely the interval $[0,\lambda(K)]$. I must say though, the answers on math.SE are rather detailed already (I just checked it), so I'm not sure what the OP has in mind.

Comment: @PierrePC I posted the question both here and in math.SE. You're right, the answers in math.SE are rather detailed but they were posted after my question on mathoverflow. Anyway, your comments were useful for me! Thank you!